# How to read files from each subfolder by giving preference to inner environment folder first in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, file, asp.net-core

I have a folder structure like this -

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   └── files3.txt
├── folder2
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   └── files6.txt
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.txt
```

I have a root folder `Products` and then bunch of sub-folders inside it. Each of those sub-folder has bunch of files in it. Just for simplicity I came up with sub-folders name as `folder{number}` and files name as `files{number}.json` or `.txt` but in general they have different names. In general I have 20 different sub-folders inside root folder and each sub-folder has around 30 files max.

Below is the code which reads above folder structure and read all the files from it. In the below code `path` variable has `Products` value which is the root folder name.

```
private IList<string> ReadFiles(string path)
{
    var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var textFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 
    var allFiles = new List<string>(jsonFiles);
    allFiles.AddRange(textFiles);
    return allFiles;
}
```

**Problem Statement**

Now I have to change my folder structure in a different format as shown below:

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files1.json
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   ├── files3.txt
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files1.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files1.json
├── folder2
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files5.json
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   ├── files6.txt
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files5.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files5.json
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.txt
```

For example - Inside `folder1` sub-folder there are three more sub-folders `dev`, `stage` and `prod` and exactly same thing for other sub-folders `folder2` and `folder3`. Each of those `dev`, `stage` and `prod` sub-folder inside each sub-folder will have files which are overridden for them.

Now I need to update my above code in such a way so that when it reads the file from `Products` root folder, it should take whatever is in `dev` folder for each sub-folder as first preference (meaning it should override if same file is present at sub-folder level) and then everything else (other files) it should take from corresponding sub-folder. So for example this should be the way it should read all the files from each sub-folders for above example -

**For folder1 -**

- It should read `files1.json` from dev folder of folder1.
- It should read `files2.json` from folder1 level.
- It should read `files3.txt` from folder1 level.

**For folder2 -**

- It should read `files5.json` from dev folder of folder2.
- It should read `files4.json` from folder2 level.
- It should read `files6.txt` from folder2 level.

**For folder3** it should read all files from that level only since it doesn't have any environment specific folders.

How should I modify my above `C#` code so that it can give preference/priority to all the files from `dev` folder for each sub-folder first and then remaining files it can read from corresponding sub-folder hierarchy.

Comment: So you're saying you no longer like SearchOption.AllDirectories.  That happens, use Directory.EnumerateFiles() instead and recurse as desired.

Comment: What does "give preference" mean?

Comment: @JonathanWood For example if `file1` is present inside `folder1` level and also we have same `file1` inside `dev` folder of `folder1` but totally different content so my code should use `file1` from `dev` folder of `folder1` not `file1` from `folder1` level. That's what preference means here basically. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Create a class / struct which has the full path of the file, as well as extra properties. a) Boolean whether it is in a dev folder or not. b) "Adapted" path - which is the same as the full path, but with `dev` removed if it is there. Now add all of the files to a `List<YourNewType>`. Now create a `Dictionary<string, YourNewType>`. Order your list by the a) boolean descending (i.e. have the dev ones first) and add them in order (if they don't exist) to the dictionary, keyed by b). Net effect - all files you want in the dictionary with priority given to the dev ones (added first).

Comment: I find this question bordering on too broad, and more like a "write teh code for me" sort of question. The fundamental issue here is that you haven't _written_ any code that would exclude files, so of course no files are excluded. There is the secondary problem that you retrieve all of the files at the same time, so you don't have a convenient way to distinguish files found in the "dev" directory, or even those found in other "environment" directories. You should start by writing a real _specification_. All you've posted here are some examples, which is not a specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I modify my above C# code so that it can give
> preference/priority to all the files from dev folder for each
> sub-folder first and then remaining files it can read from
> corresponding sub-folder hierarchy.

To achieve this,you only need to add some logic code.

First get the name of the `three-level folder` under the `Products` folder, and then determine how to add the file to allFiles **by judging whether it contains the name of the dev folder**.

If it does, use the **SequenceEqual** method to compare the file in dev with the file under folder, If the content is the same, add the file in dev. If there is no dev folder, directly add the files under the folder to allFiles.

### Update

Here is the logic code:

```
 private static List<string> ReadFiles(string path)
   { 
            var allFiles = new List<string>();
            var subFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList();
            var fileType = new List<string>() { "*.json", "*.txt" };
            for (int i = 0; i < fileType.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var sub in subFolders)
                {
                    var subSubFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sub).ToList();
                    var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sub, fileType[i], SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => !subSubFolders.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
                    var subDev = Directory.GetFiles(sub, fileType[i], SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.Contains("dev")).ToList();
                    foreach (var item in jsonFiles)
                    {
                        var dd = subDev.Where(x => (Path.GetFileName(x) == Path.GetFileName(item))).FirstOrDefault();
                        allFiles.Add(dd == null ? item : dd);
                    }
                    var extraFileDev = subDev.Where(x => !jsonFiles.Any(y => y.Contains(Path.GetFileName(x)))).ToList();
                    foreach (var item in extraFileDev)
                    {
                        allFiles.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return allFiles;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your example but I am seeing some issues. I updated my question with the issue and what I tried. Can you take a look and let me know if I did something wrong? When I run your example somehow it doesn't have files from dev folder and also it includes stage and prod files as  well which I don't want.

Comment: @cs98, I’m sorry I didn’t take the `prod` and `stage` folders into consideration, and I understood some of the problems backwards, but I have updated the code and tested everything possible with me. I think the updated code is exactly what you want, hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out in a bit but I was curious do we need to add `stage` and `prod` name as the constant in `RemoveAll` line to remove it? Can it not be done in such a way so that it takes only `dev` folder into consideration and all other inner environment sub-folders inside `folder1`, `folder2` or .... `folderx` will be removed automatically? Let's say if in future if I have some other environment folder which I also want to remove then I don't want to change this code to add that environment folder constant. It will be great if it can work as it is. Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: Ok I tried your code and I noticed one more thing and apart from that it looks good - It could be possible that I can have some new file in each environment folders (dev or stage or prod) which is not present in the upper subfolder level so I want to bring that new dev file as well in the final list. For example - let's say if we have a `folder4` which has files 35 and 36 and then inside `dev` folder of `folder4` there is a file 38 then in the final list I want that file 38 along with 35 and 36 also.

Comment: Idea is whatever is in dev folder it should be present in the final list. If the file in dev is same as present in subfolder level then it will override that file otherwise it's a new file anyway so it should be present in the final list.

Comment: @cs98, so if a file in dev has the same name as a file under subFolder, regardless of whether the content is the same, according to what you mean, the file in dev should be selected and displayed in the final list?

Comment: @cs98, you mentioned that it is possible to make other folders such as `prod` and `stage`  become dynamically deleted. I updated the answer again, but now the only thing that needs to be determined is that the files in `dev` need to be displayed in any case in the final list?

Answer (score 1):

This query works for me:

```
IEnumerable<string> query =
    from directory in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(products) //1
    let dev = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "dev") //2
    from file in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory) //3
    let fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file) //4
    let dev_file = System.IO.Path.Combine(dev, fi.Name) //5
    select System.IO.File.Exists(dev_file) ? dev_file : file; //6
```

1. get each subfolder in the "Product" path - folder1, folder2, folder3
2. create a path for a possible "dev" subfolder
3. get each file from the current folder
4. get the System.IO.FileInfo object for the file
5. create a path for a possible matching file in the "dev" subfolder
6. if the dev subfolder file exists then use that otherwise use the regular file

I get:

```
...\Products\folder1\dev\file1.txt 
...\Products\folder1\file2.txt 
...\Products\folder1\file3.txt 
...\Products\folder2\file4.txt 
...\Products\folder2\dev\file5.txt 
...\Products\folder2\file6.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file10.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file7.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file8.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file9.txt
```

---

Based on your comments below here's query that works:

```
IEnumerable<string> query =
    from directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(products)
    let dev = Path.Combine(directory, "dev")
    from ext in new [] { "txt", "json" }
    from file in 
        Enumerable
            .Concat(
                Directory.Exists(dev)
                    ? Directory.EnumerateFiles(dev, $"*.{ext}")
                    : Enumerable.Empty<string>(),
                Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, $"*.{ext}"))
            .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
            .GroupBy(f => f.Name)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
            .Select(x => x.FullName)
    select file;
```

I get:

```
...\Products\folder1\dev\file1.txt 
...\Products\folder1\dev\file42.txt 
...\Products\folder1\file2.txt 
...\Products\folder1\file3.txt 
...\Products\folder1\dev\file84.json 
...\Products\folder1\file4.json 
...\Products\folder2\dev\file5.txt 
...\Products\folder2\file4.txt 
...\Products\folder2\file6.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file10.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file7.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file8.txt 
...\Products\folder3\file9.txt
```

Comment: interesting solution.I am new to C# like a month old only. Can you let me know how above code works? I don't think it will compile as it is right?

Comment: @cs98 - It compiles just fine. I test all code before posting. You might just need a reference to the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: @cs98 - `products` is the path to your "Products" folder.

Comment: Yeah I tried and it works on my above case but it doesn't work for this case. Idea is if a file in dev has the same name as a file under subFolder, regardless of whether the content is the same, the file in dev should be selected and displayed in the final list. So if file in dev is new and its not present in the subFolder level then it should be added in the final list but if the file in dev is same as subfolder level then I will ignore that file from subfolder level but add dev file in the final list.

Comment: For example if in folder4, if I have file 35 and 36 but in dev folder I have file 38 then in my final list I also want file38 from dev along with file 35 and file 36

Comment: @cs98 - I don't see that requirement in your question?

Comment: When I wrote this line in the title and in my question - " by giving preference to inner environment folder" I assumed it was clear but it's my bad I guess.